# c# - Download the contents of an online file to a string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-3.5

I want to download the content of a .txt file located on my website to a string using c#.
I've tried with `DownloadStringAsync(Uri, String)`, but it doesn't work and the string stays blank. If I try with `string_name = DownloadStringAsync(Uri)`, it gives me the "cannot convert a void to a string" error.
I'm using the .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DownloadStringAsync wait for request completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071076/downloadstringasync-wait-for-request-completion)

Comment: @mjw Thank you, the solution to that question helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(url)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you use Encoding you can set the WebClient's property inbefore to get the right result, and use `.Dispose()` on the webclient afterwards.

Comment: The solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071076/downloadstringasync-wait-for-request-completion) was the answer I was searching for

Comment: Well you only stated that you want to download a string. Nothing about why you'd want it to happen async here. Happy you found it though ^^

Comment: I thought is was obvious since I used DownloadStringAsync in my examples